# Flask-SQLAlchemy makes INSERT statements when I create Model instances

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing a small project to learn SQLAlchemy and I'm doing it with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy. The project is intended to model a bunch of TV shows and their episodes.

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best practices when it comes to INSERT OR UPDATE (or "upserts") in SQLAlchemy, but I can't get past this road block. It seems that whenever I create a Model instance, SQLAlchemy (or Flask-SQLAlchemy) makes an `INSERT` statement! That's weird and I don't think that's right, but maybe I've missed something?

Here a simplified version of the `Episode` model, which uses a composite primary key consisting of values from three columns, of which one is a foreign key to the `Show` model:

```
class Episode(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(256))
    season = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    episode = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # relationships
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('show.id'), primary_key=True)
    show = db.relationship('Show', backref=db.backref('episodes', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Here is the code which seems to generate an `INSERT` statement:

```
show = Show.query.filter_by(something=139).first()
ep = Episode(**{'title': 'foo',
                'show': show,
                'season': 39,
                'episode': 1})
db.session.commit()
```

I'm guessing that this has to do with me referencing a persistent object, but surely this shouldn't generate an `INSERT`?

Any help appreciated!

I'm using Python 2.7 on a Windows system. I'm using Flask 0.10.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy 1.0 and SQLAlchemy 0.8.3, all installed via pip.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to only add an episode if it exists? Otherwise you want to update it with the data you provide? But the show in this case is already present in the database in both cases?

Comment: That's actually beside the point, but I want to *update* an existing episode (based on the primary keys) if it exists, *otherwise* insert it. The problem I'm having is actually not related to that at all -- the problem is that I *only* create an instance, I never actually add it, but I still see an INSERT statement in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to so-called [cascades](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#cascades). In a nutshell it works like this: If you one of the object you are working with is already in the session (in this case `Show`, since you queried it from the database through a session) then it will also *cascade* this to other objects that are related to this one.

If you don't want that, there is a way to disable this behaviour:

```
    show = db.relationship('Show', backref=db.backref('episodes', lazy='dynamic'), cascade=None)
```

I am not a 100% sure that `None` is the correct value, because I cannot find this in the documentation, I only find that `False` indicates "use default".

As a sidenote, I am wondering why you are doing it this way. From what I read in the description of the problem, I'd rather do it kind of like this:

```
ep = Episode.query.filter(Episode.show_id == 139).filter(Episode.season == 39).filter(Episode.episode == 1).first()
if ep:
    # update
else:
    # create new
```

Comment: The reason why I'm doing this is because I don't want to be so explicit about querying for an existing episode to decide whether I should update or insert. I've read a bit about `session.merge` which seems usable and as this is a learning experience, I want to venture into that part of SQLAlchemy to try it myself before taking "the easy way out".

Comment: I tried using both `cascade=None` and `cascade=''` and neither of them seem to fix the problem. The `INSERT` is still being executed. :(

Comment: Hmm, sorry then I am stuck as well. Maybe ask the list, they are usually very fast and very helpful

Comment: I fixed it by putting the `cascade` parameter on the backref instead of the relationship.

Comment: You can also set `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False` if you want to disable this behaviour for all models.